# $[U \cap H : G \cap H] \le [U :G]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is this always true that $[U \cap H : G \cap H] \le [U :G]$ , where U is a group and $G,H$ are subgroups of $U$?

My trials for $\mathbb{Z}$ were giving affirmative answer but how to prove it, if it is true?

Clearly if $H$ lies between $G$ and $U$ properly, then inequality is strict, but if not then we have to prove that  $[ H : G \cap H] \le [U :G]$ , and by second isomorphism theorem $[ H : G \cap H]=[HG:G]$, but $HG $ doesn't have to be a subgroup unless one of $G$ or $H$ is normal.

Comment: At least in the finite case, it is still the case that the set $HG$ has cardinality $\frac{|H||G|}{|H \cap G|},$ a fact which is proved in many texts

Comment: @GeoffRobinson That's true, but the result is true and not hard to prove in complete generality (even if $|U:G|$ is an infinite cardinal), so it is preferable to give a general proof even if you are only interested in the finite case.

Answer (score 2):

Well you have to stand by your definitions. Let :

$$f:U\cap H\rightarrow U/G $$

$$h\mapsto hG$$

The function $f$ is well defined. Now I would like to show that $f$ can be quotiented by the relation modulo $G\cap H$. Then we have by definition of $U/G$, for $h_1,h_2\in U\cap H$ :

$$f(h_1)=f(h_2)\Leftrightarrow h_2^{-1}h_1\in G$$

But, you always have $h_1,h_2\in H$ so $h_2^{-1}h_1\in H$. Hence :

$$f(h_1)=f(h_2)\Leftrightarrow h_2^{-1}h_1\in G\cap H$$

This equivalence shows two things. By the $\Leftarrow$ part you get that $f$ induces a function modulo $G\cap H$ and by the $\Rightarrow$ part, the induced function is injective.

This shows that $f$ induces an injective function (because this is an equivalence) modulo $G\cap H$ :

$$\overline{f}: U\cap H/G\cap H\rightarrow U/G $$

$$hG\cap H\rightarrow hG $$

Now by injectivity :

$$[U\cap H:G\cap H]:=|U\cap H/G\cap H|\leq  |U/G|=:[U:G] $$

Comment: The solution is fine, but I really dislike your use of the notation $G/U$!

Comment: @DerekHolt, I am open to any suggestion of improvement that could make my solution more clear. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a good alternative for the set of cosets, so I should not complain!

Comment: What about $\;H^{\backslash G}\;$ , knowing that $\;U\le G\;$ ?

Comment: But $U$ isn't a subgroup of $G$; $G$ is a subgroup of $U$, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, you are true, I will edit. I always take $G$ to be the big group, I have been misguided by this. Thank you for pointing this out (+1).

Comment: @ClémentGuérin An unfortunate choice of notation by the OP ($U$ being the ambient group). Anyway, my suggestion for the set of left cosets of $U$ modulo $G$ is...ta-daa! $(U/G)_L$ ($L$ stands for "left").

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas, for right cosets (in $U$ mod $G$) I usually use $G\backslash U$, it seems more graphic  than $(U/G)_R$ to me.